# Unable to create XGBoost DMatrix

Tags: python, scikit-learn, xgboost

*What i understand is DMatrix accepts numpy.ndarray as input.
I have tried this multiple times now and its not letting me create a DMatrix.*

[image: Error Screenshot]

*I have tried using Xgboost.DMatrix and Xgboost.sklearn.DMatrix.
Any help would be high appreciable.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like your y_train is a numpy array with non-numerical elements. You should transform y_train elements to numerical type.

You can do it that way:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
encoder = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
```